# Same code, different errors: Python init()

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, cryptography, init

Me and my friend are working for a University project.
Trying to execute the exactly same code, i get a error and he does not.

My error is: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'backend'`

I though that was a Python Version issue, but that's actually the same version. Any idea?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQODH.png)

File 1:

```
from pwn import *
from binascii import hexlify,unhexlify
import ciphersuite_aesnotrand as ciphersuite

port = input()

r = remote("localhost", port)

print(r.recvline().decode())
print(r.recvline().decode())

r.sendline('0')

print(r.recvline().decode())

m = hexlify(b'Test message 12!').decode()
r.sendline(m)

cph = r.recvline()
print("Received ciphertext:")
print(cph)

print("\n")

# Security parameter (fixed)
KEYLEN = 16
# Contol final decision
result = 1

for i in range(16777216): # 2^3^8 possible keys
    
    keyNumberI = bytearray(b'\x00'*(KEYLEN-3))
    keyNumberI.extend((i).to_bytes(3, byteorder = 'big'))
    
    if(i==1000000):
        print("1 milhão de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==2000000):
        print("2 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==3000000):
        print("3 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==4000000):
        print("4 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==5000000):
        print("5 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==6000000):
        print("6 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==7000000):
        print("7 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==8000000):
        print("8 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==9000000):
        print("9 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==10000000):
        print("10 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==11000000):
        print("11 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==12000000):
        print("12 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==13000000):
        print("13 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==14000000):
        print("14 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==15000000):
        print("15 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    if(i==16000000):
        print("16 milhões de chaves testadas.")
    
    cphTest = ciphersuite.enc(keyNumberI, unhexlify(m))
    
    if(cphTest==cph[:-1]):
        mTest = ciphersuite.dec(keyNumberI, cph[:-1])
        print("Mensagem resultante: ")
        print(mTest)
        result = 0
        break

r.sendline('1')

print(r.recvline())

if(result==1):
    print(1)
    r.sendline('1')
else:
    print(0)
    r.sendline('0')

print(r.recvline().decode())

r.close()
```

That's a server / client programm. But the error its from file2.

File 2:

```
# Python Module ciphersuite
import os
import random
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes

# Security parameter (fixed)
KEYLEN = 16

# Use crypto random generation to get a key with up to 3 random bytes
def gen(): 
    sysrand = random.SystemRandom()
    offset = sysrand.randint(1,3)
    key = bytearray(b'\x00'*(KEYLEN-offset)) 
    key.extend(os.urandom(offset))
    return bytes(key)

def enc(k, m):
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(k), modes.ECB())
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    cph = b""
    cph += encryptor.update(m)
    cph += encryptor.finalize()
    return cph

def dec(k, c):
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(k), modes.ECB())
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    msg = b""
    msg += decryptor.update(c)
    msg += decryptor.finalize()
    return msg
```

Thanks :)

Comment: It's difficult to guess the reason out of a gazillion possibilities. Please include a relevant block of code that you are having issue with.

Comment: This specific error is not version related. You definitely instantiate you objects differently.

Comment: Please share both codes

Comment: I think you mean __init__(self)

Comment: @L.Grozinger can't you see he cryptography is a module he is using.

Comment: Where is your class in which you are using init?

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer both codes are exactly the same.

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer not using at all!

Comment: `Cipher` use three arguments `algorithm`, `mode` and `backend` but you have provided 2 arguments `algorithm` and `mode`. you need to provide the `backend` also

Comment: @sahasrara62 that part is my professor code. Why it goes well in my friends pcs and not in mine?

Comment: Probably the versions of the `cryptography` package are different. `backend` used to be a positional argument in older versions, now it is optional

Comment: check if both of you are using same python and package version, i suggest you to create  pip list from your friend pc and install all package in ur pc then run or create a virtual env and then install package and run , see difference then

Comment: Thanks @L.Grozinger, that was the package version!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's a version problem with cryptography. Try

`pip install cryptography --upgrade`

EDIT: if not, try to uninstall pip

Answer (score 2):

Cryptography changed 'backend' from a mandatory argument to an optional argument from version 3.1. Of course, it's always best to use the latest version, especially for cryptographic libraries. If for some reason you're not able to upgrade to the latest version then you can make some minor changes to fix it.

You can check which arguments are necessary by calling help:

```
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher
>>> help(Cipher.__init__)
Help on function __init__ in module cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.base:

__init__(self, algorithm, mode, backend)
    Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
```

From the cryptography docs:
https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/backends/index.html#getting-a-backend

> Cryptography was designed to support multiple cryptographic backends, but consumers rarely need this flexibility. Starting with version 3.1 backend arguments are optional and the default backend will automatically be selected if none is specified.
>
> On older versions you can get the default backend by calling default_backend().

So you can change file2 to include the default backend:

```
# Python Module ciphersuite
import os
import random
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
# get the default backend
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

# Security parameter (fixed)
KEYLEN = 16

# Use crypto random generation to get a key with up to 3 random bytes
def gen(): 
    sysrand = random.SystemRandom()
    offset = sysrand.randint(1,3)
    key = bytearray(b'\x00'*(KEYLEN-offset)) 
    key.extend(os.urandom(offset))
    return bytes(key)

def enc(k, m):
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(k), modes.ECB(), default_backend())
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    cph = b""
    cph += encryptor.update(m)
    cph += encryptor.finalize()
    return cph

def dec(k, c):
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(k), modes.ECB(), default_backend())
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    msg = b""
    msg += decryptor.update(c)
    msg += decryptor.finalize()
    return msg
```